# I wrote 'chflags -R nouchg' on terminal accidently. Will there be any issue?

Tags: macos

I was trying to delete a locked file but managed to delete it in other way. Will the command that I wrote cause any issues? Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nouchg` keyword instructs `chflags` to turn off the
*user immutable file* flag, thereby unlocking the file.

One usually does that so as to be able to delete files or folders that are
otherwise blocked, for example to delete something in the Trash through
normal means.

It shouldn't cause any problem, but if in doubt, reboot.